# ограничение вывода дочерних категорий

Tags: smarty

Приветствую, помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку в выводе дочерних категорий с ограничением.

```
                                <ul class="example">    

                                    $count = 0

                                    {foreach $c->subcategories as $cat}

                                        {if $count<9}
                                            <li>
                                                <a {if $category->id == $cat->id}class="active"{/if} href="catalog/{$cat->url}" data-category="{$cat->id}">{$cat->name|escape}</a>          
                                            </li>
                                        {$count++}  

                                        {else} 
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="catalog/{$c->url}" data-category="{$c->id}">
                                                Все категории</a>
                                            </li>  
                                            <break>                    
                                        {/if}   

                                    {/foreach}  


                                </ul>
```

не совершенство в том , что при количестве вложенности менее 9 выводиться только ссылка Все категории, не могу найти решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$count = 0` - это объявление переменной, в smarty нужно взять в фигурные скобки.

`break` также - это не тег.

```
<ul class="example">    
    {$count = 0}
    {foreach $c->subcategories as $cat}
        {if $count<9}
            <li>
                <a {if $category->id == $cat->id}class="active"{/if} href="catalog/{$cat->url}" data-category="{$cat->id}">
                    {$cat->name|escape}
                </a>          
            </li>
        {else} 
            <li>
                <a href="catalog/{$c->url}" data-category="{$c->id}">
                    Все категории
                </a>
            </li>
            {break;}  
        {/if}
        {$count++}
    {/foreach}  
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает !